# .htaccess redirect all request to subfolder only if not specifed ip

Tags: .htaccess

I cant figure out how to redirect all requests except my ip to a subfolder in .htaccess

I came up with

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=123.45.67.89
RewriteRule ^$ /coming-soon/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/coming-soon [R=301]
```

But when i write in browser for example `example.com/asdasdas` it gives me

`coming-soon/coming-soon/coming-soon/coming-soon/coming-soon/coming-soon/coming-soon/coming-soon`

What i would like to achieve is when user enters anything that it redirects to `example.com/coming-soon` unless it is my IP. I did research on SO, but I always get stuck.

Also there is a folder in the root /coming-soon with images and fonts for that html

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=123.45.67.89
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/coming-soon [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/coming-soon [R=301,L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache or use a different browser to test this code.